# How do I insert a universally coordinated time into a PostgreSQL TIMESTAMP column?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

My database and client are currently in America/New_York, but could be moved anywhere.

```
SHOW TIMEZONE; -- America/New_York

CREATE TABLE times (
  t TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO times VALUES
  (NOW()),
  (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');

SELECT t FROM times;
-- 2017-06-13 14:53:17.766969
-- 2017-06-13 18:53:17.766969
```

This is unexpected. I thought my SELECT would return the same value for both records.

When I insert the current time into column `t`, I want it to mean the current time in any time zone (whether the database stores the underlying value as current time UTC or not). This way, regardless of the time zone the database is operating in, or the time zone the client is operating in, everybody can agree on the universally coordinated fixed point in time.

What is the proper way to INSERT a record so that everyone in the world knows I'm referencing a 'UTC' time?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking - why not just use `NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` if you want the UTC value? Then document that it *will* always be UTC, and you're okay, right?

Comment: If I `SELECT t AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM times;` that returns:
-- 2017-06-13 10:53:17.766969
-- 2017-06-13 14:53:17.766969
I'm not sure what is going on in the storage layer. But INSERT at UTC and SELECT at UTC seem incoherent to me.

Comment: I *suspect* (given the values you've said) `SELECT t AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` is effectively saying, "Assume the values in the table are in UTC, and convert them to local time."

Comment: This: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT-TABLE would somewhat agree with that, if the resulting "timestamp with time zone" is implicitly converted to the system local zone... (I agree that SQL databases in general have made a real mess of this, admittedly.)

Comment: Ah, yes, that is the behavior. I see how to document this: "always insert using `NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` and select without specifying a time zone to retrieve the UTC timestamp."

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me as a workaround for the data type not being terribly helpful. But I'm not a DB person - maybe a Postgresql expert will have a more nuanced opinion.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems like SELECT assumes that timestamp without time zone fields are stored in the local time zone. Try `SET TIME ZONE 'UTC+<n>`. The output of `SELECT` does not change (i.e., it's not as if timestamp means UTC if no timezone is stored!)

When a field it of type `timestamp with time zone`, `SELECT` correctly converts the output to the current time zone.

So when you say `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` you convert the time to UTC, then discard the timezone making Postgres think you are dealing with local time.

You can re-introduce the UTC time zone by adding another `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` clause:

```
# select pg_typeof(now() at time zone 'utc');
timestamp without time zone

# select pg_typeof(now() at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'utc'); 
timestamp with time zone
```

Bottom line: I would either always use a `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` or always have the database time zone set to `UTC` if you insist on working without time zones. The storage size of both types seems identical (64 bit).